# How to build something like Facebook Music Bridge?

Tags: facebook, flash

I notice that when I pay a song on Rdio from Facebook the communication happens completely client side. I wonder if anybody here knows how to implement something like that.

I noticed the use a `swf` file by Facebook also a call to `music_bridge_play.php` which makes me wonder it's really server side.